# How can I return a PHP $_POST array as string that is usable as a name attribute?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, tail-recursion, postdata

## Question:

I have an array of post values that looks like:

```
$_POST['children'] = array(
[0]=>array(
'fname' => 'name',
'mname' => 'mname',
'lname' => 'lname,
'dob' => '10/17/1992
),
[1]=>array(
'fname' => 'name',
'mname' => 'mname',
'lname' => 'lname,
'dob' => '10/17/1992
),
[2]=>array(
'fname' => 'name',
'mname' => 'mname',
'lname' => 'lname,
'dob' => '10/17/1992
)
);
// and so on
```

I have a script set up in my my view functions that checks for old input, and repopulates the values in the case that the form does not validate. I need to find a way to return the above array as a series of key/value pairs i.e.

```
'children[0][fname]' = 'name'
'children[0][mname]' = 'mname'
'children[0][lname]' = 'lname'
// ... and so on for all fields
```

Ideally, I would like this to work with an array of any depth, which makes me think I need some sort of recursive function to format the keys. I am having a terrible time getting my head around how to do this.

## What I have tried

I have been working with the following function:

```
function flatten($post_data, $prefix = '') {
    $result = array();
    foreach($post_data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if($prefix == ''){
                $result = $result + flatten($value, $prefix. $key );    
            }else{
                $result = $result + flatten($value, $prefix. '[' . $key . ']'); 
            }

        }
        else {
            $result[$prefix . $key .''] = $value;
        }

    }
    return $result;
}
```

This gets me somewhat close, but isn't quite right. It returns the following when I feed it my $_POST array

```
[children[1]fname] => test
[children[1]mname] => test
[children[1]lname] => test
[children[1]dob] => 
// Expecting: children[1][fname] => test
// ...
```

Or is there potentially an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me:

```
function flatten($post_data, $prefix = '') {
    $result = array();
    foreach($post_data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if($prefix == ''){
                $result = $result + flatten($value, $prefix. $key );    
            }else{
                $result = $result + flatten($value, $prefix. '[' . $key . ']'); 
            }

        }
        else {
            if( $prefix == ''){
                $result[$prefix . $key.''] = $value;
            }else{
                $result[$prefix . '['.$key.']'.''] = $value;
            } 

        }

    }
    return $result;
}
```

it wasn't accounting for the return value of the last call of the recursive function being a scalar value. The addition of these this if/else statement seems to have resolved it.

```
if( $prefix == ''){
    $result[$prefix . $key.''] = $value;
}else{
    $result[$prefix . '['.$key.']'.''] = $value;
}
```